# Convert 2 element list into dict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I know about few of the questions answered here on SO about `dict(list)` i.e.

```
l = [['a',1] ['b',2]]
```

and do `dict(l)` then we get:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

But how to make a list with 2 elements

```
l = ['a',1]
```

become a dictionary such as:

```
{'a':1}
```

using the `dict` function?

Comment: You will have to use `dict([l])` (or `dict((l,))`)

Comment: @fredtantini assuming that there's only one dictionary key/value pair in the list.

Comment: I tried dict(list(l)) and that wasn't working as I kinda guessed about converting a list into nested list but the solution i.e. dict([l]) is counter intuitive

Comment: I really don't understand the downvote on this question.

Comment: @TarunSapra: Maybe you should answer the `how many elements?` question.

Comment: @Rawing - I have mentioned it in the question a list having 2 elements

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dict` expects an iterable of two-item iterables, so you will need to put `l` in a list:

```
>>> l = ['a',1]
>>> dict([l])
{'a': 1}
>>>
```

Note that you could also use a tuple:

```
>>> l = ['a',1]
>>> dict((l,))
{'a': 1}
>>>
```

Comment: This assumes that there is only one key/value pair.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - i have specified it in the question - Convert 2 element list into dict

Comment: @TarunSapra: and several people (including me) missed that. I've edited that detail into your question.

Answer (score 1):

This works for multiple elements in the list

```
>>> l = ['a',1,'b',2]
>>> i = [(l[i],l[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(l),2)]
>>> dict(i)
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

For one element, `dict([l])` would work. For multiple key/value pairs in a flattened list, you could use `zip()`:

```
In [5]: l = ['a', 1, 'b', 2]

In [6]: dict(zip(l[::2], l[1::2]))
Out[6]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: Hey what congruency ... Even I used `['a',1,'b',2]`

Comment: @BhargavRao: That's the example in the question, isn't it? :-)

Comment: Woah ... Yeah, I hadn't seen that :)